# Could not use cases with ws-aa class file

Tags: math-mode

I am preparing a paper which will be submitted to a journal of World Scientific publisher. They recommend author use package: `ws-aa.cls` file as the following link: http://www.worldscientific.com/page/aa/stylefiles-readme-2e.

I use `ws-aa.tex` file to type manuscript. Then I could not use the following command:

```
\[
\omega(x)=
\begin{cases} 
\phi\left(\frac x{|x|}\right)\qquad\text{if $x\neq0$},&\\
\quad0\quad\;\;\;\qquad\text{if $x=0$},&\\
\end{cases}
\]
```

How could I do this?

Comment: With cases, you can use `&` between your equation and the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the `ws-aa` class tries hard to be incompatible with the most useful package for math typesetting.

It should be reported to the maintainers that their definition of the `equation*` environment clashes with `amsmath` while essentially doing the same thing as the environment defined by the package. Also the very old and deprecated way for including EPS files should be removed and changed into the more flexible `graphicx` style.

Your problem can be solved by stretching things a bit:

```
\documentclass{ws-aa}

\expandafter\let\csname equation*\endcsname\relax
\expandafter\let\csname endequation*\endcsname\relax
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

...

\section{General Appearance}

Contributions to the \emph{Analysis and Applications} will
mostly be processed by using the authors' source
files. These should be submitted with the manuscripts, and resubmitted
in the final form if a paper requires revision before being accepted
\[
\omega(x)=
\begin{cases}
\phi\left(\dfrac{x}{|x|}\right) & \text{if $x\neq0$},\\
0                               & \text{if $x=0$},
\end{cases}
\]
for publication.

...

\end{document}
```

Notice where the `&` should be placed so that there's no need to guess the spacing for aligning the conditions and `\dfrac` for the fraction.

[image]

Final note. The last update to the class was in 2005, when commands such as `\it` had been obsolete for ten years. The `graphics` package superseded `epsf.sty` at the same time of LaTeX2e release and `graphicx` was released a few years later. It's really amazing to see how bad habits perpetuate: the `ws-aa` class documentation is full of `\it` commands and even of `\over` that's not even documented in the original edition of the LaTeX manual.

Comment: Ow I did it, thank you very much. It made me crazy.